# HowTo login with PHP (and Curl) into DirectAdmin

Tags: php, post, curl, authentication

Hey guys, I am trying to create a script that will pull the log's from DirectAdmin so they can be parsed and submitted to a DB, the problem is the login of DirectAdmin.

I tried lots of script but I cant seem to get it to work...

Current script:

```
$url = 'http://213.247.000.000:2222/CMD_SHOW_LOG?domain=mydomain.com&type=log';
$username = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxx';
    $fields = array(
        'username'=>urlencode($username),
        'password'=>urlencode($password)
        );
    $fields_string='';
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { 
        $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
    }
    rtrim($fields_string,'&');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if($result===false) {
        echo 'CURL ERROR: '.curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got it!

Made a little function out of it:

```
function getlog($ip,$username,$password,$domain) {
    $url = 'http://'.$ip.':2222';

    // set temp cookie
    $ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE"); 

    // make list of POST fields
    $fields = array(
        'referer' =>urlencode('/'),
        'username'=>urlencode($username),
        'password'=>urlencode($password)
        );
    $fields_string='';
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { 
        $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
    }
    rtrim($fields_string,'&');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url.'/CMD_LOGIN');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if($result===false) {
        die('CURL ERROR: '.curl_error($ch));
    } else {
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url.'/CMD_SHOW_LOG?domain='.$domain.'&type=log');
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if($result===false) {
            die('CURL ERROR: '.curl_error($ch));
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would probably better use the [DirectAdmin PHP API class](http://www.phpkode.com/source/s/php-directadmin/php-directadmin/directadmin.inc.php).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to figure out what is being sent when you login using your browser.

You then run your curl request through fiddler and make sure the exact same thing is posted.

You might need to set a refer, user-agent or cookies. You have too look at the request to tell what you need to send.

[Web developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) is a useful tool to disable cookies and javascript. See if you can login without cookies or javascript.

Use firebug will let you know if there are any ajax requests going on behind the scenes.

Blindly posting using curl will drive you insane.

Comment: I did, with FireBug and Live Http Headers, the only 2 important fields are username and password...

Comment: You really should use fiddler. If there is a redirect going on, you will miss it.

Comment: @junke1990 you need to send all values in the form, not the only user name and password. have you checked the Byron suggestions?

Comment: I installed fiddler and run it but what am I looking for, I don't really see anything I didn't know before.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to url-encode your username/password. Just pass the regular array to CURL, and it'll take care of the encoding.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields);
```

Comment: The problem is, he is not storing & sending cookies, due to which the next request redirects him to some login page due to un-authentication

Comment: @marc not url-encoding does fix it.

Comment: @Adeel So letting curl set a cookie and sending that along would do the trick?

Comment: @Adeel still no luck... 

dump of the header and script: [link]http://pastebin.com/aAvJeBVS

Comment: @junke: What's the body of the page(s) you're receiving? The headers look fine.